# JPA illegalStateException - CascadeType issues

Tags: java, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I was hoping someone can shed some light on this for me. I do not really understand what is going wrong with this error. I have an entity that I am using to create a number of entries in the database. I get an illegalStateException when the transaction ends and a sync is done. this is all in the process of populating a db from a Web Service providing all the data. Right now I have the data parsed in a fashion that would not cause any foreign key constraint errors but the relations with the entities is stopping me.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: entities.cmic.ajrs.com.Categories[pkId=null].
```

The entity I am trying to persist is called ProductBase. ProductBase has a foreign key titled pkBrand to the Brand_Data table with the corresponding entity BrandData.

I could set the CascadeType to ALL for these relations,but I really do not want to create that entity at this time.

Here are the entities(minus some getters and setters)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_base")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findByPkId", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p WHERE p.pkId = :pkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findByColorsAvail", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p WHERE p.colorsAvail = :colorsAvail"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findBySeriesName", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p WHERE p.seriesName = :seriesName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findByStatusCodes", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p WHERE p.statusCodes = :statusCodes"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProductBase.findByTs", query = "SELECT p FROM ProductBase p WHERE p.ts = :ts")})
public class ProductBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer pkId;
    @Column(name = "colors_avail")
    private String colorsAvail;
    @Column(name = "series_name")
    private String seriesName;
    @Column(name = "status_codes")
    private String statusCodes;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ts")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date ts;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductSorts> productSortsCollection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MapTarget mapTarget;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private KeyFeatures keyFeatures;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk_category", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Categories categories;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk_brand", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private BrandData brandData;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<PromotionsByModel> promotionsByModelCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductEnhancedFeatures> productEnhancementFeaturesCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<SkuBasic> skuBasicCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductMeasurements> productMeasurementsCollection;

    public ProductBase() {
    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "brand_data")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BrandData.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BrandData b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BrandData.findByPkId", query = "SELECT b FROM BrandData b WHERE b.pkId = :pkId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BrandData.findByCommonBrandId", query = "SELECT b FROM BrandData b WHERE b.commonBrandId = :commonBrandId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BrandData.findByCommonBrandName", query = "SELECT b FROM BrandData b WHERE b.commonBrandName = :commonBrandName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BrandData.findByTs", query = "SELECT b FROM BrandData b WHERE b.ts = :ts")})
public class BrandData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer pkId;
    @Column(name = "common_brand_id")
    private String commonBrandId;
    @Column(name = "common_brand_name")
    private String commonBrandName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ts")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date ts;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "brandData", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ProductBase> productBaseCollection;

    public BrandData() {
    }
```

Comment: Bad use of plural class names...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception clearly says that `ProductBase` references unsaved instance of `Categories`.

If it's intentional and you actually want to save new instance of `Categories`, you can configure cascading for that relationship or save that instance manually before saving `ProductBase`.

Otherwise, if `ProductBase` should reference existing persistent instance of `Categories`, you need to load that instance from the database instead of creating the new one.

Comment: Thank You. That is what I was thinking the problem was. I tried committing the Categories saves first but had no luck with that. I will get back to looking at that.